# Conditional INNER JOIN or LEFT JOIN based on the joining condition

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, inner-join

I have a query

```
SELECT
  users.email AS email,
  addons.sku AS sku,
  addons.quantity as quantity,
 invoices.total as total

FROM addons

INNER JOIN users ON 1=1
  and users.id = addons.user_id

LEFT JOIN invoices ON 1=1
  AND invoices.user_id = users.id
  AND invoices.status != 3
```

Here is what I need to happen:

- if user doesn't have an invoice at all we should include them with `NULL` being returned in the `total`
- if user has an invoice in status `!= 3` we should include them
- if invoices exists and status = 3 we should exclude them.

So it's like I need both `INNER JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN` at the same time

How can I achieve that?

Comment: now if an invoice exists with status = 3 it's still showing up in the results. If I replace LEFT with INNER it behaves like I desribed :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
SELECT
  users.email AS email,
  addons.sku AS sku,
  addons.quantity as quantity,
  invoices.total as total
FROM addons
INNER JOIN users
  ON users.id = addons.user_id
LEFT JOIN invoices 
  ON invoices.user_id = users.id
WHERE invoices.status IS NULL OR invoices.status != 3
```

Explanation:

- Users without invoices are included in the result, with "empty" invoice total. That's what the `LEFT JOIN` is for
- Users with invoice status != 3 are included, and so are their invoices. So, add that to the where clause (remember the `status` could be `NULL` because of the above `LEFT JOIN`)
- Users with invoice status = 3 are excluded. Do that with the `WHERE` clause

Comment: piece, love, gum